# Why isn't QToolButton's icon displayed?

Tags: qt, button, resources, icons, stylesheet

I meet the problem, so I take a test at MainWindow, the problem remains the same.
Here is the code in "MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)..."

```
QToolButton* bt = new QToolButton(this);
bt->setIcon(QIcon(":/te.png"));
bt->setToolButtonStyle(Qt::ToolButtonIconOnly);
bt->show();
```

It looks like:
    [image]

My resource file is like this:
    [image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have given the icon an alias `te` but called the icon by it's full name `te.png`.  Use `:/te` instead.